# Assembly resource loader IsXaml or not

Tags: c#, xaml, .net-assembly

I try to create resource loader. However I have small issue. How can I replace **IsXaml** and write Nunit test (simulate xaml file) ?

```
    public static string GetPartialName(this Assembly assembly)
    {
        var fullName = assembly.FullName;
        var startIndex = fullName.IndexOf(',');
        return fullName.Remove(startIndex);
    }

    public static Uri GetResourceUri(this Assembly assembly, string resource)
    {
        string path;
        if (IsXaml)
        {
            path = $"pack://application:,,,/{assembly.GetPartialName()};component/{resource}";
        }
        else
        {
            path = $"/{assembly.GetPartialName()};component/{resource}";
        }
        return new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    }
```

Thanks